# Zend_Filter and Zend_Validate for names with apostrophes

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hey guys, quick question, just trying to filter a user's first and last name via Zend_Filter, but some users could obviously be irish or something else.  Does anyone have a filter and validate extension for this?  Thx for your time guys.

Comment: I don't see a problem as long as you are consistently using UTF-8 as encoding.

Comment: It's their name - why try to filter this at all? The dude that legally changed his name to contain a "2" won't enjoy the false negative this script would throw out. Just make sure the value isn't blank or all whitespace and proceed.

Comment: I think the OP means validation in general. Of course he has to validate the user input and if there is no Zend_Validate validator that suits for names with uncommon signs like O'Hara then he needs to write a custom validator, which is, I think, what he's asking for. The validator which is normally used for that is 'Alnum' and I remember I've seen a way to add accepted chars, I just couldn't find anything about it in the manual now.

Comment: Hey guys, I appreciate the responses.  Yeah I'm mainly looking for a validator or an easy way to add an allowable character, otherwise i'll just write one myself.  As for the filter, I was thinking just incase they misstyped, but yeah probably unnecessary anyway.  Thx again guys.

Comment: The real question is what are the disallowed characters? :) IMO there ane no disallowed characters. You should only escape the name properly on output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to implement a Regex Validator, with something like

```
 \w+[']?\w+
```

as the regex, depending on the placement/count of apostrophes

If you are not using Zend Form,  This is a way to do it.

```
         $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

            //Filters Apply first before Validators.
            $filterRules = array();  


            //Validators are applied after Filtering.
            $validatorRules = array( 
                   'first_name' => array( 
                          new Zend_Validate_Regex('/\w+[']?\w+/'), 
                         'presence' => 'required', 
                         'allowEmpty' => false, 
                         'messages' => 'Blah Blah ));

   $input = new Zend_Filter_Input($filterRules, $validatorRules, $data);
```

Syntax may be off, and regex may not be to spec, but im sure you can figure out a regex.